# Stop Selenium 2.0 Webdriver from creating temp files IE

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I run my script a temp file gets created in my local directory: 
something like: "webdriver4726826335276373500libs"
inside the folder: IEDriver.dll

at first I thought it was this issue 
[How to stop Selenium from creating temporary Firefox Profiles using Web Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787095/how-to-stop-selenium-from-creating-temporary-firefox-profiles-using-web-driver)
but that does not seem to be the case, I do not think that IEdriver uses profiles.

This is a problem for me because it is eating up my hd space. 
does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of the IE driver is contained in a COM dll written in C++. For certain language bindings (.NET and Java), this dll is extracted at runtime to a temp folder when you instantiate an instance of the InternetExplorerDriver class. These languages then use their native code invocation mechanism (JNA or P/Invoke) to call the functions in the native code dll. This methodology was chosen to reduce the requirement on the user to have the correct .dll (and the correct version of the .dll) in a known location. At present, it doesn't appear that the Java language bindings do anything to delete this .dll after the server is shut down, whereas the .NET bindings do. The report tracking this issue for the Java bindings in the project's issue list is [issue #1140](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1140). As a workaround, you can manually delete these directories after running your tests, or it may be possible to create a short routine in your testing framework that will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The driver.quite() will automatically clears your temporary files. you better look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184828/how-to-delete-temporary-files-which-is-generated-during-selenium-webdriver-runs).