# How to delete temporary files which is generated during selenium webdriver runs?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me to delete the temporary files  generated  during the web driver test runs?
i am using selenium web driver 1.25 and IE 7.Implementing my test in java.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure you call

```
driver.quit();
```

instead of

```
driver.close();
```

close() will not delete temporary files

Answer (score 3):

The temporary files are deleted automatically once you had used driver.quit() in the latest versions of Webdriver. Can't be sure. **Is it 1.25 or 2.25 ?**

Comment: Thats fine. though, i just want to explicitly do it in the finally block. Can you please assist me to achieve this?

Comment: @Karthikeyan  You need to write driver.quit() in finally then

Comment: Automation_User: :P i don't what my browser to be closed, does it work for driver.close?

Comment: @Karthikeyan It doen't work for driver.close(). It works only for driver.quit()

Comment: They really are not. At least not until recently. In older releases, larger files are not deleted with quit(). It was a huge pain in the rear building a Java FX browser for automating all forms of ingestion requiring framework interaction, logins and etc. to have it fail due to a Byte Decoder leak (Oracle fix March 2017) and issues with frameworks when viewstates are missing images and things. Recently, it appears that this is working better. I still recommend using a deleteOnExit hook and specifying a directory for temp files in your profiles.