# How do I enable popups in a new Firefox profile using selenium webdriver (Java)

Tags: selenium, popup, webdriver

The application I am testing requires pop-up to be enabled. When a launch a new Firefox profile I get the browser message

> Firefox prevented this site from opening a pop-up window

with a button on the right called Options. I can manually click the Options button and select to Allow popups from ....

Question is how can I use `profile.setPreference` to set to allow popups from my website and also not show this Firefox message?

Answer (score -1):

You can save your current Firefox prifile with allowed popups and load it from file like in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6830109/1165331

save you current working profile with popups via browser and loat it.

Comment: After I create a new profile I want to use profile.setPreference to allow popups.

Comment: You can configure browser to allow popups manually, and save your profile after it. Your preference will be inside the profile. When load profile to webdriver.