# ChromeDriver/Chrome filling up system temp Folder

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium 2.35.0 to access web pages in a loop by calling chromedriver_win32_2.3/chromedriver.exe. Sometimes an exception would happen (Time out etc.) and something would create a lot of scoped_dir****_** folders and gradually filling up the disk space.

The strange thing is even if I reboot the computer, the writing continues after restart. The only way to stop this is to delete the user account.

I looked at the running processes and could not find anything unusual.
Any explanation on why this happens?

Comment: There was similar issue for firefox here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787095/how-to-stop-selenium-from-creating-temporary-firefox-profiles-using-web-driver .

Comment: Madusudanan: I looked through the link you provided, the problem seems to be different. A potentially useful part is to delete the temporary files in case the WebDriver cannot start. However, it does work in my case.

Comment: The scoped dir is the counterpart of firefox's anonymous webdriver profile folders.They are created by chromedriver,the issue seems to be still open, See-> https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1934. I have faced this similar issue and as of now I am clearing the temp files manually.Perhaps you could try not closing your browser and use clear cookies functionality that comes with webdriver for each browser.Spawning a new browser creates many temp folders like that.

Comment: I have the same problem on one of my selenium grid machines. I updated the chromedriver.exe to version 2.4 and now the scoped_dir** files/folders seem to get deleted after both successfull and failed tests.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question trying to solve my own problem. This is what worked for me.
I am using instance of my ScrapeTest class. in my class definition I have the following destructor,

```
def __del__(self):
    """ close webdriver
    """
    self.driver.close()
    self.driver.quit()
```

Even though the destructor get called after each run, it was not working until I use `del` to delete my **scraper** instance explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in chromedriver that has been fixed and resurfaced several times. It will be [fixed again in Chromedriver 2.30](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=644) which hasn't been released yet.