# Use stored cache for WebDriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Each time I run new firefox driver it takes 1 minute to load it vs 5 seconds to load with cache. Is there any capability to use stored cache while running new firefox driver? (or doesn't flush previous webdriver cache with particular name)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should set webdriver.firefox.profile property to name of the profile. Refer ([How to stop Selenium from creating temporary Firefox Profiles using Web Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787095/how-to-stop-selenium-from-creating-temporary-firefox-profiles-using-web-driver)) for detail.