# Firefox launches then closes with "Firefox has failed to launch (selenium 2.53.2)

Tags: selenium, firefox

I'm having a problem when launching Firefox from Selenium (using version 2.53.2).
When I launch it using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

it launches, then straight away tries to close with a "Firefox has stopped working" error.

This has been working previously, I tried to uninstall and reinstall Firefox, but I'm still getting the same problem every time.
I don't get the issue if I launch Firefox manually.

Comment: try to launch it with existing profile. If it works, then something is wrong with profile creation. If it fails, then something is problematic with selenium plug-in accessing firefox

Comment: I tried to run:

fp=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

but still got the same error

Comment: that still creates a new profile. Try like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24650405/5318223

Comment: Still getting the error after running the following (I'm still new to this, so not sure if I created the profile correctly?):

import os

from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)

driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)

Comment: you are still creating a new profile though. I was suggesting to try with existing profile, i.e. create profile named, for example, "test", and load it as described in that solution (`new ProfilesIni().getProfile("test");`)

Comment: I managed to create a new profile on Firefox, but I can't get the ProfilesIni () function to work.

It's recognising the command, is there another library that I need to import? I'm only importing webdriver

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue with Firefox 47: 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1279127