# C# Selenium open temporary Firefox Profiles how to stop it?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, firefox-profile

> How to open same selenium profile none temporary  copy from my profile
>   I need the same firefox profile in C#

I already read this article:

[How to stop Selenium from creating temporary Firefox Profiles using Web Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787095/how-to-stop-selenium-from-creating-temporary-firefox-profiles-using-web-driver)

But it's not work with me also I use C#, not java I tried using:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.firefox.profile", "Profile0", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

but still, create new temporary from the profile I choose but I need the same profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer it is not possible to stop selenium creating temporary profiles

[How to stop Selenium from creating temporary Firefox Profiles using Web Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787095/how-to-stop-selenium-from-creating-temporary-firefox-profiles-using-web-driver)